# Link in tag subscription e-mail is not correctly formatted

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, email

I'd like to report that the link to this site is not rendered correctly in tag subscription emails.

[image: email screenshot]

Comment: It does not answer the question but is indeed a duplicate bug report.

Comment: Hopefully that'll be status-completed and then the problem will be solved ;)  Just follow it.